# Can't seem to select Date range picker by it's XPATH using selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to **scrape** data from http://covid.gov.pk/stats/pakistan. I want the script to be able to click the date range picker to change the dates, but I cannot seem to select it the XPATH I am using is as follows.

```
//*[@id="body"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/lego-report/lego-canvas-container/div/file-drop-zone/span/content-section/canvas-component[66]
```

Python script I am using

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get("http://covid.gov.pk/stats/pakistan")

#wait for Page to load
WebDriverWait(driver, 30, ).until(EC.invisibility_of_element((By.XPATH, "//div[@id=\"preloader\"]")))

#select date range picker
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"body\"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/lego-report/lego-canvas-container/div/file-drop-zone/span/content-section/canvas-component[66]")
element.click()
```

The error I encounter is as follows

> Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="body"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/lego-report/lego-canvas-container/div/file-drop-zone/span/content-section/canvas-component[66]"}
> (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.113)

I can not seem to figure out what exactly isn't working I copied the xpath by inspecting the element using developer tools in chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date picker element is present inside an `iframe`.You need to switch the `iframe` first to access the date picker.

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`() and use following css selector.

Then you can click on date picker using following xpath.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://covid.gov.pk/stats/pakistan")
#wait for Page to load
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.invisibility_of_element((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='preloader']")))
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".pak-stats-ifrm")))
#select date range picker
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='content-holder ng-scope']")
element.click()
```